# data- not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I create this piece of code to create dinamically pop-ups, but is not working in IE8.

The Can i use is telling me that the IE8 have partial support for this feature -> http://caniuse.com/#search=data-

This is the code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="popup" data-ride="popup"></div>
  <a href="#" data-popup="open">Abrir</a>
  <a href="#" data-popup="close">Fechar</a>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  function PopUp(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.width = '100%';
    this.height = '100%';

    this.setSize();
  }

  PopUp.prototype.setSize = function() {
    var self = this;

    $(self.element).css('width', self.width);
    $(self.element).css('height', self.height);
  };


  var clickHandler = function (e) {
    var element = this;
    var action = $(element).data('popup');

    if (action === 'close') {
      $('.popup').hide();
    } else {
      $('.popup').show();
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  };

  $(document).on('click', '[data-popup]', clickHandler);

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-ride="popup"]').each(function () {
      var $popup = $(this);
      $popup = new PopUp($popup);
    });
  });

}(jQuery);
```

Is working 100% in IE9+, Firefox and Chrome.

Example:

http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/yyWqWm

Comment: What part isn't working? Are errors thrown? More debugging info would help

Comment: that's because i don't have charlie.. is just not working, the popup is not showing when i click in open :B... no errors..

Comment: Well there are numerous things you should find out such as if the event is firing, if any errors are being thrown etc. Please create a demo that replicates the problem

Comment: just a sec @charlietfl

Comment: http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/yyWqWm

Comment: does the same thing in IE8 for me as it does in chrome or firefox, overlay shows up all black

Comment: thats so strange, could you send me a pic? I believe in you, but i want show to my boss.

Comment: lol it never works in IE 8

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation for IE 10 - IE 8, you have to use jQuery's `attr()` function.

on this line, `var action = $(element).data('popup');`

You need `var action = $(element).attr('data-popup');`

Comment: where is this documented? Have never had problems using `data()` in IE myself

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=data-   *Partial support refers to being able to use data-* attributes and access them using getAttribute. *

Comment: but that's how jQuery accesses it, and has worked in IE ever since `data()` was introduced

Comment: You can access it using `attr()` as well. An attribute is an attribute, regardless of what it's called. `data()` is just shorthand.

Comment: understood but that doesn't mean you have to either. Again, have never encountered this issue using `data()` going back to when it was set to read attributes in 1.4

Comment: Did some research and I think you're right. In fact, they tell you to use `data()` for grabbing those elements. Misread the *CaniUse* website =\

Comment: jQuery has always been pretty good at managing cross browser issues which is partly why I was confused by your original answer